# No symbol in shared library of implemented parent method

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a class `AbsAlgorithm` which has 3 virtual methods:

```
class AbsAlgorithm
{
public:
    //..... other methods
    virtual void run() = 0;
    virtual bool init(TestCase&) = 0;
    virtual bool done() = 0;
};
```

I have created a static library, `libAlgatorc.a`, containing this class.

I have also class `SortingAbsAlgorithm`, which inherits from `AbsAlgorithm` and overrides the methods `run`, `init` and `done`.

```
class SortingAbsAlgorithm : public AbsAlgorithm
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        execute(...);
    }

    bool done()
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I create a shared library containing this class (and some other classes) I don't have symbols for `SortingAbsAlgorithm::run`, `SortingAbsAlgorithm::init` and `SortingAbsAlgorithm::done` in the shared library. Why?

I create the shared library like this:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -fPIC SortingAbsAlgorithm.cpp SortingTestSetIterator.cpp SortingTestCase.cpp  -shared -o libProject.so -Wl,--whole-archive -lAlgatorc -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Comment: Did you define those pure virtual functions? If  they are only declared, not defined, what could possibly be output in the library? Or are you asking about the overrides in `SortingAbsAlgorithm`? (It's not clear which symbols you are asking about).

Comment: Even after your edit it's still not clear which symbols you are asking about. Are you expecting to see symbols for `AbsAlgorithm::run`, or `SortingAbsAlgorithm::run`, or both?

Comment: I am expecting to see SortingAbsAlgorithm::run. I suppose that there won't be any AbsAlgorithm::run symbol

Comment: OK, then your question is contradictory, because you said _"Is this because this methods are pure virtual methods?"_ and `SortingAbsAlgorithm::run` is not pure virtual

Comment: Ok. I've deleted that sentence. What could be then possibly wrong that SortingAbsAlgorithm::run symbol is not in my shared lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't see any symbols for the pure virtual functions in the base class unless you write definitions for them, as the compiler cannot possibly output any symbol for a definition that doesn't exist.

You also won't see any definitions for the overrides in the derived class unless you call them, and probably only if you call them and compile without optimisations.

This is because they are defined as inline functions (because you defined  them in the class body) and so according to [dcl.fct.spec]/4 in the C++ standard the compiler knows that any other callers of those functions in other object files can also see the function definitions, and so there is no need to emit extern symbols when compiling `SortingAbsAlgorithm.cpp`.

If you want to ensure that the compiler outputs the definitions of those functions  then do not define them as inline functions. Alternatively, if you have code in the library that constructs an instance of `SortingAbsAlgorithm` that will also ensure that the library contains symbols for the virtual functions (but not for any other inline functions that aren't called in the library).

Comment: So basicly I can call them but I can't see them in shared lib. If I load this dynamic lib in my main program and create instance of class SortingAbsAlgorithm I can call method run, done and init? Is this correct?

Comment: If your main program sees the definition of `SortingAbsAlgorithm` then it will be able to call them, because the functions are defined inline and your main program can see their definitions. If the main program can create an instance of the class, it must be able to see its definition, so it can see the functions too.